# Regarding jQuery & BlockUI plugin

Tags: jquery

we know that we can block any element using jQuery BlockUI. like the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#blockButton2').click(function() { 
        $('div.test').block({ 
            message: '<h1>Processing</h1>', 
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

using the above code it block my div and a another little message comes with text processing... but i want bit different. i want that when i will block any element then a div layer will come on the element with the same height and width of that element and a busy image and text processing will come in the center on the blocking layer. so please guide me how to get the effect using block UI. what i need to add. please guide. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean "element blocking"? http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element

Okay, it looks like you do. To get an image in there just add the HTML to the "message" propoerty. The example on the link above shows the message in the center?